# Referencing DLL's among different environments

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, dll, dllregistration

I am trying to create some powershell cmdlets that can be placed on a few different environments. These environments have various versions of sharepoint installed and so the location of the Microsoft.Sharepoint DLL file changes depending on the version installed.

Within the cmdlets i am then looking to use sharepoint objects e.g. **SPFarm.BuildVersion;** so as I can then tailor the rest of the cmdlet.

My problem is that I dont't know how to reference the dll when the location can change between environments, and I need to add the using statement in the code to access the SP objects.

I hope this makes sense....any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "different environments"? Different versions of SharePoint?

Comment: Basic sharepoint assemblies are located in GAC so should be good to go with [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

Comment: by different environments I mean I have different VM's with different versions of sharepoint on the different VM's. As to using the [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") i'm not sure how to use that in a visual studio project where i am creating the cmdlet. I realise that I can use it directly in powershell just not sure about visual studio